# Deployed rails app to Elastic beanstalk can't connect to RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my app to Elastic Beanstalk by following [this tutorial](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git).

The app works if I use `splite3`, but I can't connect the app to RDS.

I added `group :production do gem 'mysql2' end` in Gemfile, and this code to `config/database.yml`.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

I added RDS in [Elastic Beanstalk console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

But `production.log` shows error, that indicates DB connection fails.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/app/support/logs/production.log
-------------------------------------
I, [2014-02-09T16:01:56.520967 #29379]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2014-02-09 16:01:56 +0000
I, [2014-02-09T16:01:56.620738 #29379]  INFO -- : Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
E, [2014-02-09T16:01:56.629835 #29379] ERROR -- : Mysql2::Error: Table 'ebdb.posts' doesn't exist: SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts`
I, [2014-02-09T16:01:56.630802 #29379]  INFO -- :   Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.3ms)
I, [2014-02-09T16:01:56.631068 #29379]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms
F, [2014-02-09T16:01:56.633962 #29379] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Table 'ebdb.posts' doesn't exist: SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts`):
```

`eb status` shows like this.

```
URL     : myAppURL
Status      : Ready
Health      : Green

RDS Database: AWSEBRDSDatabase | myDatabaseURL:port
```

Probably I miss something very basic. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: You do connect to RDS as your app would crash at startup if you couldn't. It just does not find the table. Can you connect to RDS and run "use yourdatabasename;" and "show tables;" and take a look? Maybe just a migration missing on your production DB?

Comment: Are you using a RDS instance created by the EB process or you are connecting your EB app to an already existing RDS DB?

Comment: HEy!! I have the same problem... I hava managed to connect to my RDS Database vis Sequel client for SQL, and have observed that the database 'ebdb' exists, But contains no tables or content at all!!... I believe this might be the case for you too, so it MUST be a problem of rails migrations not running properly for some reason... any idea how to check if they're running, run them manually, or see the output of the db_migrate command done in the elastic beanstalk environment ?

Answer (score 1):

If your database is not named `ebdb` you could hardcode your database name in the YAML file:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_database_name
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```